# Is an RST pin the same as a microcontroller NRST pin?

Tags: pcb, stm32, reset, pinout

I am currently working on a PCB design using a STM32F411CEU6 microcontroller. In order to debug the circuit using an ST-Link, I have placed a header in order to access the pins in the microcontroller. I have a question regarding the NRST pin. The STlink says it has a "RST" pin, however the microcontroller has an NRST pin. Is there an issue if i connect this two?[image]

Comment: NRST may be a reset pin and you can find out whether it is active-low or active-high for your particular uC. However pin_RST is a user label and only you know what it is connected to. I see it connected (or getting potentially connected) to SWCLK which doesn't exactly sound like a reset signal but it may be.

Answer (score 2):

NRST is just a shorthand way of indicating that the reset pin is active-low (negative-RESET) since it's not always easy to create the word with a line over it. Your MCU symbol is actually a bit confusing since it shows NRST as being inverted.

The STLINK RESET output pin is active-low and is intended to be connected directly to the MCU NRST input pin. Refer to the [STLINK manual](https://file:///C:/Users/Spehro/Downloads/um1075-stlinkv2-incircuit-debuggerprogrammer-for-stm8-and-stm32-stmicroelectronics%20(8).pdf) if you are using the genuine ST product.